# Will a compound index be used to provide a resultset if the selected column(s) are contained therein?

Tags: sql

To me this should be an obvious answer, but I can't be certain all SQL implementations adhere to this retrieval strategy.

Consider the following table definition:

```
pk (int)
col1 (guid)
col2 (char)
col3 (int)
...
```

upon which is defined a non-clustered non-unique composite index (col1, col2, col3)

if following query is executed:

```
select col3 from myTable where col1 = blah and col2 = blah2
```

...do most if not all database products (SQL Server, Sybase, etc.) return the col3 from the index itself, never hitting the actual table?

Comment: Assuming that the table has more columns (if not, what would be the difference in hitting the index instead of the table?), then in SQL Server you would be doing a "covering index" for your query, meaning that it won't be necessary to go to the table

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My full question would be: how likely is it that any given (major) database product supports the notion of a "covering index"?

Comment: Thanks to the terminology lead of covering index by Lamak, I now know which term to research for and have discovered broad support for this query strategy, including Sybase, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, and even MySql.

Comment: @Sean Would you be so kind as to make that an answer with the relevant information for others? You can mark your own answer as the correct one after (IIRC) 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the terminology lead of covering index by Lamak, I now know which term to research for and have discovered broad support for this query strategy, including Sybase, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, and even MySql